# Word for the strong liking people have towards the smell of petrol/gasoline

Tags: word-request

Is there any particular word for the strong liking some people have toward the smell of gasoline?

Comment: Not that I know of, but [here's an article](https://www.discovermagazine.com/health/why-some-people-love-the-smell-of-gasoline) that discusses this phenomenon. Is there a word for it in your native language?

Comment: My native language ? Well, that's what I am asking :)   Thanks for the link!

Comment: @userabc It's worth noting that this site is mostly intended for learners of English as an second or extra language.  So when someome posts a word request, it is common to ask if the word exists in their native langauge.  Our sister site english.stackexchange.com is better if you are a native speaker of English, but read their guides on how to make single word requests.

Answer (score 1):

It's called ***petrol sniffing*** and the person who does that is called a ***[petrol sniffer](https://www.lexico.com/definition/petrol_sniffer)***.

> **Petrol sniffing:** The practice or habit of inhaling petrol fumes for a narcotic effect. [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/petrol_sniffing)

Or perhaps *petrol smell addiction* or *[euosmia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euosmia)*.

I don't think there's any other word for it.

Comment: It should be noted there is a big difference between someone who deliberately inhales petrol *fumes* for narcotic effect and someone who just likes the smell of petrol. To get a narcotic high from petrol you have to deliberately smell it at close range. You can smell petrol while you're on a garage forecourt, but you don't get high from it.

Comment: Some people even drink raw petroleum spirit especially before unpalatable or toxic additives are incorporated. It has been noted in refinery employees. Also, ether drinking was more common in the medical profession 100 years ago than it is now. Needless to say, both these practices are very bad for health.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I was a big *ether sniffer* back in the day.

Comment: I know of someone who lost his eyebrows and some hair (and was lucky that was all) when sniffing ether, when a room full of vapour and air mixture ignited. It is habit forming and the condition of being habituated is called etheromania. A rich vapour/air mixture can be explosive, and if (e.g. in a lab) pure oxygen is involved, very likely to be so. The dangers to health, life, and limb, of monkeying with volatile compounds can scarcely be exaggerated. How do I know all this? I am married to a pharmaceutical manufacturing lab manager.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific term for someone who likes the smell of petrol, although it is a recognised phenomenon. There may be some other related terms you could work into an explanation.

[This article](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/623813/reason-why-some-people-love-smell-of-gasoline) explains that it is just another form of **nostalgia** which is triggered by the smell. This is related to **olfactory memory**, or our memory of smells.

Some people habitually smell things, even things which they know are unpleasant. This behaviour has been [termed](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2015/08/03/why-do-people-sometimes-like-stinky-things/) "**benign masochism**".

Someone who has a heightened sense of smell might be said to have **hyperosmia**. These are likely to be more sensitive to smells and have a stronger olfactory memory.

Comment: My first wife strongly craved the smell of Dettol, a disinfectant containing 4‐chloro‐3,5‐dimethylphenol, when she was pregnant with our first child, and used to pour a little in a sink to savour the aroma.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Pregnancy is one of the major causes of transient **hyperosmia**.